# SQL Query Help - LIKE Statement

Tags: sql, string, where-clause, exists, sql-like

```
SELECT  Name
FROM    Names n
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT NameIDs FROM NameList nl WHERE n.nameID LIKE '%'+nl.nameIDs);
```

I'm trying to query this table and it only seems to return the first values. Name list is a comma seperated value cell and there can be multiple occurences of it.

I was wondering if anyone could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its comma separated then you need to have the wildcard % after the nl.nameIDs too as the value can occurr anywhere in the middle of the comma separated string.

```
SELECT  Name
FROM    Names n
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT NameIDs FROM NameList nl WHERE n.nameID LIKE '%'+nl.nameIDs+'%');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the comparison backwards.  Try this:

```
SELECT  Name
FROM    Names n
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT NameIDs FROM NameList nl WHERE ','+nl.nameIDS+',' like '%,'+n.nameID+',%'
```